# Serializing List<MemoryStream> to a file using a standard .NET class

Tags: list, silverlight, windows-phone-8, serialization, memorystream

Writing a WP8 Silverlight app. Is there a standard .NET technique available in this environment I can use to serialize an object like this

```cs
private static List<MemoryStream> MemoryStreamList = new List<MemoryStream>();
```

to save it to a file and restore it later?

I tried to use DataContractJsonSerializer for this which is good to serialize a List of simple custom objects, but it fails for List (I get System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException).

Comment: `BinaryFormatter` should do the job

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, I forgot to write that I need this in a WP8 Silverlight app (already corrected the question). .NET BinaryFormatter isn't available in this environment.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest converting your list to a list of byte arrays before persisting and then you should be able to serialize. Of course this comes with some overhead at deserialization as well.

Serialization part:

```
byte[] bytes = null;
var newList = MemoryStreamList.Select(x => x.ToArray()).ToList();

XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(newList.GetType());

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    ser.Serialize(ms, newList);

    //if you want your result as a string, then uncomment to lines below 

    //ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    //using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
    //{
        //string serializedStuff = sr.ReadToEnd();
    //}

    //else you can call ms.ToArray() here and persist the byte[]
    bytes = ms.ToArray();
}
```

Deserialization part:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    var result = ser.Deserialize(ms) as List<byte[]>;
}
```